# Background process capture GPIO input

Tags: gpio, process, lxsession, background

This question suggests it is doable - [Script Running in Background GPIO.cleanup() on shutdown](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/82964/script-running-in-background-gpio-cleanup-on-shutdown)?

In a desktop environment with another process displaying its window, is it possible for a background process to always be fed the GPIO inputs ? Hoping to avoid the transparent window trick.

Comment: The answer is yes.  If you want a detailed answer you need to edit your question and explain (more detail) what you want to do.

Comment: @joan Hurrah! There is a touch/mouse based piece of software that I would like to control from a just some GPIO hooked buttons. background process captures these buttons and controls the app trough a TCP pipe.

Comment: @kellogs: Those details must go ***in the question***; i.e. please edit your question.

Comment: @kellogs comments are not part of the question ... this site is not a forum